# HTML and CSS bundle for Textmate

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles

Are there any `html` and `css` bundle in `textmate` for autocompletion. Keeping track of every `div` becomes painful at some point. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "keeping track of every `div`"? What kind of autocompletion do you expect?

Comment: if i do <div> it should write </div> for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextMate's killer feature is and has always been its snippet expansion mechanism. Even now that it has been copied by every editor/IDE under the sun.

If you don't know about it or don't use it there's almost no point in chosing TextMate over any free text editor.

Just type `div` then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to expand it to

```
<div id="">

</div>
```

There are snippets like this one for the most common HTML tags, check the *Bundles* menu.

You can also type `div` or any tag name and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> to turn it in a proper tag.

You can also select some text and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to wrap it with tags.

Why don't you read [the documentation](http://manual.macromates.com/en/)? Or print out [this cheatsheet](http://www.g-design.net/textmate.pdf)? Or simply look around in TextMate's menus? TextMate costs money, if you don't put some efforts into it you have wasted your €45.63.